# Getting user IP and storing it as a variable to use in Geolocation API

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, api

I am trying to get moocher.io geolocation(https://market.mashape.com/moocher-io/ip-geolocation) working on my web app. This API requires an ip input in order to return location, etc. I am simply trying to send a get request to get the users IP because I need it to find their location automatically, without having to input the user ip.

```
$.get("http://ipinfo.io", function(response) {
alert(response.ip);
}, "jsonp");
```

That will return an ip and alert me to what that IP is. What I need to do is take that ip and plug it into my geolocation function as a variable. Here is the function in full as it is now,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var url = 'https://moocher-io-ip-geolocation-v1.p.mashape.com/' + ip;
        var ip = $.get("http://ipinfo.io", function(response) {
        alert(response.ip);
        }, "jsonp");

        $.ajax({
            url: url
            , type: 'GET'
            , dataType: 'json'
            , success: function (data) {
                console.log('SUCCESS');
                console.log(data);
                console.log(data.country);
                console.log(data.city);
                console.log(data.state);

            }
            , error: function (data) {
                console.log('ERROR');
                console.log(data);
            }
            , beforeSend: setHeaders
        });
    });
 function setHeaders(xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Mashape-Key', 
 'OURjCxSqLNmshIvDitfBhE88vFV8p1WrqCRjsnr8HkCb33A83c');
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
        }'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now the second asynchronous request is being made before you've received the ip address back from the first request.  You'll want to wait to make the request to `moocher.io` until only after you've received the response back from `ipinfo.io`.

Fortunately it's a quick fix.  You could wrap the second async request in a function and invoke that function within the callback of your first async request:

```
$.get("https://ipinfo.io", function(response) {
   alert("Initial IP address request: " + response.ip);
   mooch(response.ip);
}, "jsonp");

function mooch(ip) {
    var url = 'https://moocher-io-ip-geolocation-v1.p.mashape.com/' + ip;

  $.ajax({
    url: url
    , type: 'GET'
    , dataType: 'json'
    , success: function (data) {
      console.log('SUCCESS');
      console.log(data);
      console.log(data.ip.country);
      console.log(data.ip.city);
      console.log(data.ip.region);
    }
    , error: function (data) {
      console.log('ERROR');
      console.log(data);
    }
    , beforeSend: setHeaders
  });
}

function setHeaders(xhr) {
  xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Mashape-Key', 
                       'OURjCxSqLNmshIvDitfBhE88vFV8p1WrqCRjsnr8HkCb33A83c');
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
}
```

Note that the result data returned from `moocher.io` appears to be slightly different from your first draft (it's nested under an 'ip' key and 'state' is listed as 'region'.

https://jsfiddle.net/gco65kqy/2

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked. I was testing some different location APIs and that is how region became state and was overlooked, sloppy on my end.
Thanks again!